# Is it possible to set an initial value when initializing CBCharacteristic?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

Admittedly, I have a hard time with the wording of the Apple Docs so I might be missing something.  However, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Here's the question.

Given:

```
let charSomeUUID = CBUUID(string: "12345678-1234-12234-1234-123456789qwe")
someCharacteristic    = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: charSomeUUID, properties: [CBCharacteristicProperties.read, CBCharacteristicProperties.notify], value: nil, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.readable)
```

How would one provide an initial value for the value field?

I see how to do it in `didReceiveRead`.  But I'd like to set an initial value.

I've tried putting a string into a data object and putting it in the value spot and that doesn't seem to work.  And the swift 3 equivalent of the (Objective C) example in the Apple docs doesn't seem to work (anymore?).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not seem to work"? Could you link the Apple example that is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies.

I actually had another piece of code that was wrong that ended up being the real problem.

For future reverence here is code to show that what I originally thought would not work does, in fact, work.

```
let stringValue : String = "something"
    let dataValue = stringValue.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    // Device Info
    someCharacteristic    = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: someUUID, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties.read, value: dataValue, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.readable)
```

*NOTE: When adding a value by this method your characteristic needs to be read only.  Still some things to read up on there.*

Failing to use read only results in the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Characteristics with cached values must be read-only'
```

Sulthan, thank you for your attention.  Sorry for the mix up.